# How to add SOAP Headers to soap message- XSLT

Tags: xslt, soap

I'm getting the SOAP request with empty Headers. I want to add custom headers to the incoming request and copy the soap body as is to the response.How to add xml tags in the Headers ?
Below is the incoming request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <input>
         <numb>15171</numb>
      </input>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expected Output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header>
          <Username xmlns="http://blah.com">username</Username>
          <Password xmlns="http://blah.com">password</Password>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <input>
             <numb>15171</numb>
          </input>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my XSLT which I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   
    xmlns:soapenv="http://soap/envelope/"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  
       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="soapenv:Header">
    
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <soapenv:Header>
      <Username xmlns="http://blah.com">username</Username>
          <Password xmlns="http://blah.com">password</Password>
  
        </soapenv:Header>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="soapenv:Header"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it.
Note that your 'soapenv' namespace in your XSLT was not matching what is defined in your input XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="soapenv:Header">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Username xmlns="http://blah.com">username</Username>
      <Password xmlns="http://blah.com">password</Password>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkU